# postgresql trigger or functions for user creation storation

Tags: postgresql, triggers, user-defined-functions, plpgsql

I am not able to find user creation, password changed, userid updated or last login details in postgresql and for the same I want to create trigger or functions so that it will store database user creation time and when a database user was logged in, along with the password updated time. I want to implement this at database level and not on table level.

I am using below function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.trigger_update_created_and_modified_date()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
EXECUTE format(E'update &amp;quot;%s&amp;quot; set date_created = \'%s\', date_modified = \'%s\'
WHERE id = %s', TG_TABLE_NAME,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NEW.id);
ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
EXECUTE format(E'update &amp;quot;%s&amp;quot; set date_modified = \'%s\'
WHERE id = %s', TG_TABLE_NAME,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NEW.id);
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END

$BODY$;
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: You are talking about application users, not database users, right?

Comment: database users only

Answer (score 1):

DML triggers only fire on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements, so they cannot be used.

But there are *event triggers* that fire on `CREATE`, `ALTER` or `DROP` statements. Unfortunately for you, the [event trigger firing matrix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-matrix.html) shows that you cannot have event triggers on `CREATE/ALTER/DROP ROLE`, so there is no way to get what you want.

What you can get, and what I recommend you do, is to use the log file. Set

```
log_statement = 'ddl'
log_connections = on
```

and you will get these events logged.

You can use the `csvlog` format if you want to parse and digest these log files in an automated fashion.